# Crash logs not appearing in DashBoard

Tags: ios, objective-c, crashlytics

I have implemented crashlytics with cocoa Pods and have implemented the crash method provided and it does not reporting any crash logs in my dashboard.
In MyAppdeledate "DidFinishLaunching" method I have included this

```
[Crashlytics startWithAPIKey:@"xxxxxxx"];
[[Twitter sharedInstance] startWithConsumerKey:@"xxxx" consumerSecret:@"yyyyyyyy"];
 [Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class], [Twitter class]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric here.

If you're testing with Xcode's Simulator or a device connected to Xcode, then a crash may not show as Xcode's debugger will prevent us from capturing crashes. Here's how to [test locally](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/test-crash.html#troubleshooting) in order to ensure a crash shows up:

1. Launch the Simulator.
2. Hit Stop in Xcode.
3. Launch your app in the Simulator and cause a crash.
4. Hit Run in Xcode.
5. The crash report will show up and you can see console output indicating that the report has been sent.

Comment: its not showing any report in console or in dash board :(

Comment: Can you share the console output from the run post-crash?